# Wire connectors

Tags: electronics, connector

I'm making an Iron Man costume for Comic-Con and it has electronics in the hand and head.
I'm going to route both to the back to be handled. There is a certain type of wire connector that I want to use to connect across the shoulder and neck and I don't know what it's called. The connector is the same one that small lipo batteries and pc fans use, the one with the clip to prevent unwanted detachment but pushing on it allows for easy removal.

What is this type of wire connector called?

I uploaded some pictures to make sure you know which ones I'm taking about.

imgur.com/a/afeEw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer fans usually use Molex connectors, however there are different versions of Molex connectors:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fan#Connectors

Small LiPo batteries often use JST connectors. Again there are different versions and the Internet often does not differentiate correctly. Popular JST versions are JST XH and JST RCY. Bigger batteries might use custom connectors.
http://www.rchelicopterfun.com/rc-lipo-battery-connector.html

For examples:
(I currently can't post more than two links)
Check your favourite supplier shop and search for Molex and JST. Just as a shop-example I'll mention: [reichelt](https://www.reichelt.com/de/en/).

Comment: Also [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/), [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/), [Arrow](https://www.arrow.com/), etc.

Comment: I added a link to some photos